# How to control the margins of figures when knitting a HTML in R?

Tags: r, margin, knitr, rstudio

I plot a heatmap by heatmap.2 and it looks right in the plots panel of Rstudio. However, when I knit the HTML using knitr, it always choked at: 
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Anyways to control the figure margin? I reset the out.width and out.height in opts_chunk without success. Thank you.

Comment: haven't tested but have you tried setting `par(mar)`?

Comment: heatmap.2 has a parameter "margin" overrides the par(mar) settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try the `fig.height` and `fig.width` chunk options.  Not sure, but I think these might work because they adjust the graphics device as discussed [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/options)

Answer (score 1):

Just find out another way is simply to set "margins" in heatmap.2 into a big value, so that the plot output is small to fit the fig.width and fig.height. I tried to use par(mar) before, but just find out it can be overriden by heatmap.2.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the fig.height and fig.width options does in fact work in R Studio, in RMarkdown through knitr both in R Studio and R Terminal, and so far in every other situation where I've gotten this error message from an R plot. You might just want to make it a default to set width and height to something largish (8, 10, or 12) in every chunk that contains a plot.